# Each child List should have a unique "key" prop warning?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I keep getting the warning when I make a Scroll View list. Each child List should have a unique "key" prop warning? Im trying to make an appendable list that can add items on when you click a button. If anybody can help that would be great !

```
export default function Home ()  {
 const [people,setPeople] = useState([

  {name:'First', key:'1'},
  {name:'Second', key:'2'},
  {name:'Third', key:'3'},
  {name:'Fourth', key:'4'},
  {name:'Fifth', key:'5'},
 ])
 
  return (
    
    <View style={styles.container}>
      
    <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.Square1}>
        

        <View style={{backgroundColor:'#171651', height:340, width:400, borderRadius:10,}}>
          <Text style={{color:"white", fontWeight:'bold', marginStart:10, fontSize:30, marginTop:10}}>
            Investing
            </Text>
            <Text style={{color:"white", fontWeight:'bold', marginStart:10, fontSize:30,}}>
                $0.00
            </Text>
        </View>
        </View>
        
        <View style={{marginTop:50}}>
          <Text style={{color:'white', fontSize:20, marginStart:10}}>
            Favorites
          </Text>
        </View>

      <ScrollView>
        {people.map(item=> (       
          <TouchableOpacity>
          <View key={item.key}>
            <Text style={styles.item}>{item.name}</Text>
          </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
 
    );
  } ``
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will happen if you're ever iterating/looping (for example, array.map) and returning a component or JSX.  This is because React wants to be able to distinguish between the JSX.  In this case, you have your key on `View`.  To resolve it, you only need to shift `key` up to the parent element, `TouchableOpacity`

As per the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys),

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity:
> The best way to pick a key is to use a string that uniquely identifies a list item among its siblings. Most often you would use IDs from your data as keys:

They're important, as they assist React with keeping track of and differentiating between the components you are rendering.  Dan Abramov wrote up a nice illustration [here](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1415283502124261378).  In addition to reading the documentation I linked, I would recommend checking out Dan Abramov's tweet I just mentioned.

Comment: Thank you ! that makes iterating/looping and JSX so much more clear now! Thank you for the informative tweets! It makes the whole concept so simple.

Answer (score 1):

Shift your key prop into the `TouchableOpacity`. React expects the key prop to be in the top most element.

```
        {people.map(item=> (       
          <TouchableOpacity key={item.key}>
              <View>
                  <Text style={styles.item}>{item.name}</Text>
              </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
```

Comment: Thank you so much !!! Didnt know why I didnt think of that!